# how to build dynamically WPF toolbar?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Because ToolBarTray provider no itemsSource i'm using Toolbars as place holders but can't get it done. I have made a user control that is placed MainWindow. I used similar thing to build menu as a base for this and frankly i don't know what I'm doing. I use also the same MenuItemViewModel here. But I can't get anything to the toolbar. The menu works perfect.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ui:ToolbarButtonFilterConverter x:Key="converter" />

    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=Visibility}"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=BitmapName, Converter={x:Static ui:NativeImageResourceConverter.Default }}"/>
    </Style>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type menu:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <ToolBar Name="Toolbar1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ToolbarItems, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter=Toolbar1}"/>
    <!-- here more toolbars as placeholders -->
</ToolBarTray>
</UserControl>
```

The ToolbarViewModel seems to work ok (bound collections) because in convert below the corret item with 6 child items is returned), but xaml is probably faulty. ui:NativeImageResourceConverter is never called for these toolbar buttons that should get created from MenuItemViewModels.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var items = value as ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>;
        if (parameter != null && items != null)
        {
            if (parameter.ToString() == "Toolbar1")
            {
                return items.Where(i => i.Header == "Toolbar1");
            }
            //...
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Menu items are hiearchical and can contains children in MenuItemViewModel:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    public Visibility Visibility  { get; private set; }
    public string BitmapName { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; private set; }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> _menuItems;
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems;
    //...
 }
```

Comment: Is code for MenuItemViewModel ok ? semi-colon is missing and may-be something else too. Please check.

Comment: 1. BasedOn is not needed. 2. here : Converter={x:Static ui:NativeImageResourceConverter.Default }} , what you are trying to do ? Why not using converter as static-resource ?

Comment: Thanks!! MenuItemViewModel is in use in menu so it works pefectly. In MenuViewModel there is BasedOn similarlky, that's why I took it also here. So how exactly MenuItemViewModel knows to transform itself to a button without it? These converters suck so you gotta try all styles to make them work. Now it ended like that cause other ways didn't work. So trial and error to get it built. It's converting an image in native resource to a Image.

Comment: oh sorry the Converter={x:Static ui:NativeImageResourceConverter.Default }} was also copied from MenuViewModel. Isn't it same if it's as UserControl  static resource?